# Using separate DBContext classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I know that the `DBContext` represents a session (Unit-Of-Work and Repository) with the database, however I an unsure as to when I should have a different `DBContext`. Currently, I have a separate `DBContext` for each table with a single `DBSet` for each `DBContext`.

Something like this (`Blogs` and `Posts` are in the same database):

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }        
}

public class PostContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure why I had a separate `DBContext`. I think that it is a sample I followed that was like this. However, I recently found that I get an exception when trying to do queries involving both contexts:

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts.

So, it seems that the obvious solution is for a single `DBContext` and multiple `DBSets`:

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }        
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any guideline for when to use different `DBContext`s and the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: I suppose one option is to use the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns to manage this across a single repository, but that starts to look like quite a lot of work for a simple site.

Comment: Not sure about pros and cons but I have always used one DBContext.  I don't think I have ever seen your first example in practice (doesn't mean it's not valid though)

Comment: Thanks, not sure where I picked it up. One DBContext makes sense.

Comment: My rule of thumb would be to use a single context per app; use multiple contexts when you could be breaking down your app into multiple smaller apps. 99% of the time you would be using a single context.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you have already mentioned, DbContext *is* a UoW, and DbSet *is* a repository -- there is no need to reimplement those patterns, unless you're into ridiculously useless complexity.

Entity Framework wraps all pending changes in a transaction for you already, so each DbContext in an application contains DbSets that are somehow related. Blogs and Posts are *definitely* related, so they belong under the same context.

If your app had a blog module and a completely distinct chat module, you could use separate contexts, as your app would never be using both in the same controller.

I have an app with dozens of absolutely unrelated modules; either I defined a single context with 650 entity types (and only used a fraction of it every time), or I broke it down into *much* smaller and sanely manageable modules... I went for the second option. (the app is an ERP extension)

Comment: DbSet can not be a repository. A repository should always be an aggragate root and a Blog and Post entity collections belong to one aggreagte root becouse they can not exists without each other. And yes the DbContext is a UoW but this is a wrong implementation and should not rely on it.

Comment: Then what, ditch EF and reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @PeterKiss sorry to unearth this, but doesn't a navigation property fulfill the aggregate root requirement? You can do `context.Blogs.Where(e => e.Posts.Any())`, I don't see where it lacks. At all.

Comment: @retailcoder: no we don't need to ditch the EF but we have to create another small abstraction layer above it. Image this: we are calling methods which are saving entities to the database, when to call SaveChanges()? Always? Never? If we call it always then we can end up whith a situation when we only saving the half the currently running business transaction. And we havn't talked about that we can have transaction without a database how to handle that? A unit of work belongs to the business logic not (only) to the database abstraction.

Comment: @PeterKiss I definitely see the case for a business layer, which is what it sounds like you're describing, which would in turn leverage EF.  However, I don't see how repository pattern would be the appropriate pattern for exposing the business layer.  A repository pattern represents a set of data.  A business layer represents actions that can be performed.

Comment: "there is no need to reimplement those patterns, unless you're into ridiculously useless complexity." I'm not sure I agree. I don't like having calls to a dbcontext directly in my controllers. I like having it hide inside of a business layer that sort of, kind of, implements these patterns (with some additional business rules).

Comment: @RubberDuck you can happily wrap the DbContext with an interface and call it a day. You can even name it `IUnitOfWork` if you want, and expose a `Commit` method that calls `SaveChanges` - a UoW wraps a transaction, and so does a `DbContext`: they're one and the same. What people want to achieve with the patterns is just a layer between EF and the controller - fine; just saying an interface does exactly that for a fraction of the complexity. I simply cannot see what the problem is with a constructor-injected `IUnitOfWork`  that exposes `IDbSet<T>` for the controller to play with.